VSCode open external terminal wezterm in home folder instead of in project folder
I use Visual Studio Code on my MacBook Pro and until now I had used iTerm 2 as my terminal emulator and I had it set as the external terminal in vscode: "terminal.external.osxExec": "iTerm.app". So when I press Cmd+Shit+C vscode launches iTerm 2 in my project folder. I recently tried out WezTerm and I liked it and decided to use it instead of iTerm 2. I changed the vscode setting to open wezterm as my external terminal: "terminal.external.osxExec": "WezTerm.app". So now when I press Cmd+Shift+C vscode launches wezterm. However, it launches it in my home folder instead of my project folder which defeats the entire purpose of launching an external terminal from vscode. I tried searching online, but couldn't find anything useful. How can I configure vscode to use wezterm as my external terminal and launch it in the project's folder?

I don't know wezterm, but the question boils down to whether Wezterm can be started for a certain directory. Even in this case, I think the interesting point is whether the shell launches from wezterm starts off in your project directory. I would first research this for wezterm used by itself (outside VSC), and if this works, consider integration with VSC. In any case, I don't think this is a programming question, so you better ask this on [apple.se].

I built a plugin to solve this problem; Searching for "VSCode WezTerm Quickstart
" in the VSCode plugin or vscode-wezterm-quickstart, I hope this can solve your problem

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/134926. Different terminals have different ways of being told what working directory to start whatever program they run at, or what default they use when nothing is specified. Maintainer Daniel Imms ("Tyriar") says there that this is best left up to a support extension.
I haven't tried, so I can't really vouch for it, but Nauxscript seems to have built such an extension at Nauxscript/vscode-wezterm-quickstart.
